# jsRender - extra spaces in each loop

Tags: jquery, jsrender

HTML:

```
<div id="container"></div>

<script type="text/x-jquery-tmpl" id="tmpl">
  <div>{{=title}}</div>
  <div>
    {{#each cast}}
      {{#if $itemNumber == 1 }}{{=name}}{{else}}, {{=name}}{{/if}}        
    {{/each}}
  </div>
</script>
```

JS:

```
var json = [{ title: "Mission Impossible IV", cast: [ {name: "Tom Hanks"}, {name: "Jackie Chan"}, {name: "Tom Cruise"} ]}];

$("#container").html(
    $("#tmpl").render(json)
);
```

Rendering as this:

```
Mission Impossible IV
Tom Hanks , Jackie Chan , Tom Cruise
```

**Issue:** note the space after each name.  I don't have a space in the template however, with the tags all bunched up, `{{#if $itemNumber == 1 }}{{=name}}{{else}}, {{=name}}{{/if}}`, so, those extra spaces shouldn't be there.

**Question:** any idea as to how those extra spaces are getting in there?

You can tweak it here: http://jsbin.com/otiqun/2/edit

Comment: As a guess, the linebreak between `{{/if}}` and `{{/each}}` is probably being rendered as the additional (unwanted) space. Try removing that linebreak?

Comment: if you put this as an answer, I'll mark it as Correct. thanks man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linebreak between `{{/if}}` and `{{/each}}` is likely being rendered as the additional space, since HTML condenses any amount of consecutive whitespace characters into a single space. Try removing any unnecessary linebreaks and see if it fixes the problem.